# local's router is having trouble starting

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress-rest-api

When i open localhost and create a simple website it not me showing the website. then it showing me this problem

> local's router is having trouble starting

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below article. May it will help you out
https://mulcas.com/heads-up-locals-router-is-having-trouble-starting/

Thanks.